# data bars on the xaxis should be aligned properly

Tags: d3.js, charts

I am building my first bar chart using d3.js v5 what I want is that the bars should be aligned properly on the xaxis

I have almost done building the chart but can't figure out the problem

```
var headingOne;
var headingTwo;
var dataset;
var description;
var frequency;
var barPadding = 20;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Next time will use d3.json();
  req.open(
    "GET",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json",
    true
  );
  req.send();
  req.onload = function() {
    let json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    headingOne = json.source_name;
    headingTwo = `From ${json.from_date.substring(0,4)} to ${json.to_date.substring(0,4)}`;
    dataset = json.data;
    descripton = json.description;

    d3
      .select("body")
      .append("h1")
      .text(headingOne)
      .attr("class", "headings")
      .attr("id", "title");

    d3
      .select("body")
      .append("h2")
      .text(headingTwo)
      .attr("class", "headings");

    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40 },
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right;

    var minDate = new Date(dataset[0][0]);
    var maxDate = new Date(dataset[dataset.length - 1][0]);

    var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([barPadding, width - barPadding]);
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d[1])]).range([height, barPadding]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);

    var svg = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

    svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (width / dataset.length))
    .attr("data-date", (d) => d[0])
    .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d[1]))
    .attr("data-gdp", (d) => d[1])
    .attr("width", width / dataset.length)
    .attr("height", d => height - yScale(d[1]))





    svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate("+barPadding+"," + (height) + ")").attr("id", "x-axis").call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+", 0)").attr("id", "y-axis").call(yAxis);


  };

});
```

I expect the bars properly aligned on the xaxis.
Now the bars started before the xaxis (start of the xaxis towards left) starting point which is wrong but finished in the right position (end of the xaxis towards right) 
the data is exceeding the limit.

Comment: Try positioning the bars with the scale - that's what places your x ticks. This will move your tick to the start of the bar. If by *properly* you mean ticks in the middle you should use scaleBand which is designed for elements with width (scaleTime is not).